# How do I get correct total number of select count(*) with LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Tags: mysql

Here is my total user without JOIN statement.

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    -> FROM users;
+--------+
| total  |
+--------+
| 608000 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

And with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    -> FROM users
    ->        LEFT OUTER JOIN users_icon
    ->          ON users.uid = users_icon.iconuid
    ->        LEFT OUTER JOIN icon_code
    ->          ON users_icon.icondata = icon_code.iconid;
+--------+
| total  |
+--------+
| 608084 |
+--------+
1 row in set (3.78 sec)
```

Here I've got different total number. With the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` how do I get the total number is 608000?

Comment: Presumably because there are multiple related rows across the tables?

Comment: Try this, SELECT COUNT(users.id) AS total

Comment: Unless there's a one to one relationship between all three tables, wouldn't you expect there to be more rows when you join them all together?

Comment: @BryanMoyles should be `count(distinct id)`, the count you mentioned will give same number

Comment: Why not just use your first query? There is no advantage in using the second query if you just want to count the number of users.

Comment: @BryanMoyles count(*) and count(users.id) will give same count

Comment: @rs yes!. Now with the `distinct` and it worked!.

Comment: @eggyal what are you talking about? I said `count(*)` with joins will give same count as `count(user.id)`

Comment: @rs.:  Quite right.  I misread your comment!  Apologies.

Comment: @rs may you move your comment to answer, So I can vote & mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`count(distinct users.id)` to get correct count.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` may produces more count since, it will also count the table rows in `users_icon` and `icon_code` table. If a corresponding row in `users_icon` or `icon_code` is null, it will also count. It is the behavior of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.